# Makefile: why always use `$(MAKE)` instead of `make`?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, parallel-builds

I usually use a high level build system like `cmake` for building my C/C++ code. But for *various reasons* I am using straight GNU `make`.

I am doing recursive build where each directory has a makefile.

I recently had to change all my makefiles from using `make` to `$(MAKE)` and then parallel builds started working.

The literature I've read all say "always use `$(MAKE)`" (O'Reilly book, 5+ solutions on stackoverflow.com from people with greater than 10-40K points).

**In your makefiles, why always use `$(MAKE)` instead of `make`?**

(obviously ONE reason is because `$(MAKE)` somehow enables parallel builds.)

**Is there more happening than simple substitution of `$(MAKE)` with `make`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matthieu's answer is correct, but not complete.

The best thing to do is read the [GNU make manual section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKE-Variable.html) related to using the `MAKE` variable.

In addition to using the correct `make` executable (which is reason enough), GNU make attempts to understand which recipes invoke recursive instances of make.  Any recipe that does so is treated specially in a few ways:

First, that recipe is invoked even if you run `make -n`, `make -q`, or `make -t`.

Second, in order to communicate with its sub-makes (for example, to allow the jobserver to work properly) `make` maintains a set of open file descriptors (for pipes).  For "normal" (non-recursive) recipes make will close those file descriptors before spawning the recipe (so that (a) recipes can't accidentally mess up that communication, and (b) because some programs / scripts are written to expect specific file descriptors are unused).  For recipes that are determined to be recursive invocations, `make` will not close those file descriptors.

GNU make uses two different ways to detect whether a recipe is a recursive make, or not.  One of them is that you can add the `+` special character to the beginning of the recipe.  The second is the presence of the `$(MAKE)` (or `${MAKE}`) variable references in the recipe.

Answer (score 1):

On some systems, the executable calling make is not called `make`. For example, non-GNU systems often have a `make` command that is not GNU Make, and users have to run `gmake` if they want to use Makefiles designed for GNU Make. If you make recursive calls as `make` on these systems, the recursive calls will not call the same executable as the top-level one typed by the user. Using `$(MAKE)` ensures recursive calls will use the same "make" as the toplevel.